# Alter column should not allow nulls

Tags: sql-server, constraints, ddl

i cannot find any way to execute this - all i need is to add column but not allow nulls to
existing table.

```
ALTER TABLE IP_USER ADD troller bit DEFAULT 0
```

when i use this syntax all the rows get Null.

what is the syntax i'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always specifiy NULL or NOT NULL constraint

```
ALTER TABLE IP_USER ADD troller bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: Though `NULL` is always assumed for `ALTER COLUMN` if not specified I think.

Comment: @MartinSmith: defined here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx which in turn is part of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188340.aspx. TBH, I always specify it because it's easier